# How would I write a batch script to either minimise all cmd windows or minimise a window with a given name?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-console

The windows that I am trying to minimise are already running so `start /min` is not an option.

Comment: what have you tried on your own? Please read [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Batch commands are not capable of window controlling. You might be interested in [AutoIt](http://autoitscript.com) or [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with an `vbscript` hybrid.

```
@echo off

set "lookFor=Calculator"

for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%A in ('tasklist /nh /fo csv /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq %lookfor%"') do set "pid=%%~A"

>"%TEMP%\_edit.vbs" (
  echo/Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
  echo/oShell.AppActivate %pid%
  echo/WScript.Sleep 500
  echo/oShell.SendKeys "%% (n)" ' minimize (Alt+SpaceBar,n^)
)

start /B cmd /C "CScript //nologo //E:vbs "%TEMP%\_edit.vbs" & rem del /F /Q "%TEMP%\_edit.vbs" 2>NUL"

exit/B
```