# MySQL workbench - How to open 2 databases on load

Tags: batch-file, mysql-workbench

I use a batch file to open all my work apps.

If I use the workbench -query command line option I can get 1 database to open, except I get an annoying "Open SQL Script" dialog that I cannot find a way to suppress.

Adding 2 -query commands to the same START line does not work.

If I use 2 START lines in the batch file separated by a PAUSE both databases will load, but then I get 2 of the "Open SQL Script" dialogs and have to hit a key during the batch file execution. The pause is need as without it the second START is ignored (or fails).

**Questions :**

1) Is there a way to automatically load 2 databases in MySQL workbench?

2) Is there a way to suppress the "Open SQL Script" dialog?

Comment: perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585236/call-mvn-tomcatrun-in-multiple-projects-different-directories-using-a-batch-fil/39593222#39593222) answer may help you

Comment: about the "Open sql script" dialog, does "MySQL workwench" have not any commandline switch to avoid prompting? Also you may check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507965/how-would-i-write-a-batch-script-to-either-minimise-all-cmd-windows-or-minimise/39508924#39508924), as you may use _cscript `sendkeys` method_ to send key codes (or close window command) to the active window. what key (or window command) is the dialog waiting for?

Comment: no switch that I can find documentation for... good idea about the sendkeys